# Disable finger scrolling in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to disable scrolling in my UIScrollView, but only when the users tries to.

I can't disable UserInteraction because my UIScrollView contains UIButton which I need to keep active.

Finally, I have to keep the possibility to scroll by using that kind of code :

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(200, 0, myScrollView.frame.size.width, [myScrollView bounds].size.height);
[myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:myRect animated:YES];
```

Thanks for any solution !

Comment: have you tried using scrollEnabled property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make all the check boxes of UIScrollView's Scrollers section.

Comment: Mmmh.. I was overwriting some properties programmatically ^^ Thanks, it's working ;)